# Mesh generation in BGE

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine

Does BGE allow a mesh loader python script which could generate all meshes before a game level begins rather than just use pre-rendered model directly?

And to be more clear, I'm speaking about procedural generation. 
I want to generate mesh not necessarily during the game's runtime but during the intro/title screen/level loading(etc).

In other words, Is it possible to develop a mesh generator python script that could run before the start of every game level?

Comment: You can add meshes with the actuator, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.